# Error when drawing lines dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data file with several time series and I want to plot them all in a single graph using Javascript/D3. I am fairly new to Javascript/D3 but after searching for examples I have managed to come up with a code that almost does the trick. There is still one issue remaining, namely I face a weird problem when I try to initialize and draw my line objects dynamically.

My three code files below contain a MWE with two series. In *charts.js* I load in some data (date column and two series). I initialize my line objects in two ways: first hard coding (e.g. `line1 = d3.svg.line()`) and secondly assigning them into an array (e.g. `allLines[0] = d3.svg.line()`) allowing for dynamic initialization of the series. I try to render the lines as

```
// Version 1: Harcoded lines
allPaths[0].attr('d', line1);
allPaths[1].attr('d', line2);   
allPaths[1].style("stroke", "red")

// Version 2: Lines from array
allPaths[0].attr('d', allLines[0]);
allPaths[1].attr('d', allLines[1]);   
allPaths[1].style("stroke", "red")
```

Version 1 works just fine and both lines appear as they should. However, I encounter a weird problem when executing the lines in Version 2: when running line `allPaths[0].attr('d', allLines[0]);` **the execution somehow jumps back in the code** to the part where objects are allocated into `allLines` (or so it at least seems in debugging mode). This then throws an error of undefined object/variable and the **script fails to execute**. To me this makes absolutely no sense. Further, `allLines[0]` and `line1` seem to be equivalent so I cannot figure out why they won't produce the same result.

In summary, does anybody have an idea what could cause this weird behavior? I am also open to other ways of obtaining the desired result, i.e. being able to plot all the series in the data file dynamically.

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>D3 Line Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**chart.js**

```
var Chart = (function(window,d3) {  

  // Declare global variables
  var svg, data, x, y, xAxis, yAxis, dim, chartWrapper, line1, line2, allLines, allPaths, margin = {}, width, height;

  // Create data
  var data = [{date: "1.1.2005", serie1: 10, serie2: 15},
              {date: "1.2.2005", serie1: 14, serie2: 16},
              {date: "1.3.2005", serie1: 12, serie2: 17},
              {date: "1.4.2005", serie1: 19, serie2: 21},
              {date: "1.5.2005", serie1: 7, serie2: 13},
              {date: "1.6.2005", serie1: 12, serie2: 16},             
              ];


    // Define how dates are presented in the source file
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;

    // Format each series into its own, distinguishable elements
    color = d3.scale.category10();
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));    
    lineNames = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
          };
        })
      };
    }); 

    //Initialize scales. HACK: only selecting scales based on the 1st series
    xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d,i) { return new Date(parseDate(d.date)) });
    yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d,i) { return +d.serie1 });
    x = d3.time.scale().domain(xExtent);
    y = d3.scale.linear().domain(yExtent);

    //Initialize axes
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient('bottom');
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient('left');

    //Initialize svg
    svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg');
    chartWrapper = svg.append('g');     
    chartWrapper.append('g').classed('x axis', true);
    chartWrapper.append('g').classed('y axis', true);   


    // Create lines:

        // Version 1: Hardcoded lines
        line1 = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date))) })
          .y(function(d) { return y(+d.serie1) });

        line2 = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date))) })
          .y(function(d) { return y(+d.serie2) });          


        // Version 2: Dynamic lines
        allLines =[];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
            allLines[i] = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date))) })
                          .y(function(d) { return y( d.lineNames[i].name  ) });                   
        };


    //Paths to all lines
    allPaths =[];
    for (var i = 0; i <= allLines.length - 1; i++){
        allPaths[i] = chartWrapper.append('path').datum(data).classed('line', true);
    };  

    //render the chart
    render(data);   


  function render(data) {

    margin.top = 100;
    margin.right = 300;
    margin.left = 50;
    margin.bottom = 100;

    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



    // update x and y scales to new dimensions
    x.range([0, width]);
    y.range([height, 0]);

    // update svg elements to new dimensions
    svg
      .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    chartWrapper.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    // axes scales 
    xAxis.scale(x);
    yAxis.scale(y);

    // x-axis
    svg.select('.x.axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

    // y-axis
    svg.select('.y.axis')
      .call(yAxis);


    // Draw all lines:

        // Version 1: Harcoded lines
        allPaths[0].attr('d', line1);
        allPaths[1].attr('d', line2);   
        allPaths[1].style("stroke", "red")

        // Version 2: Lines from array. COMMENTED OUT SINCE DOESN'T WORK!
        //allPaths[0].attr('d', allLines[0]);
        //allPaths[1].attr('d', allLines[1]);   
        //allPaths[1].style("stroke", "red")        

  }
    }

)(window,d3);
```

**style.css**

```
body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) problem. The `i` in the line generator function is not the `i` you think it is.

Instead of writing a long explanation, I'll link this question (with a lot of good answers), which I hope you read thoroughly: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

That being said, this should be your loop:

```
allLines = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let thisName = lineNames[i].name;
    allLines[i] = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date)))
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d[thisName])
        });
};
```

Pay attention to the `let`, to the `<` instead of `<=` and also to the bracket notation.

Here is your updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/60erppmL/

And the same code in the Stacked snippet:

```js
var Chart = (function(window, d3) {

    // Declare global variables
    var svg, data, x, y, xAxis, yAxis, dim, chartWrapper, line1, line2, allLines, allPaths, margin = {},
      width, height;

    // Create data
    var data = [{
      date: "1.1.2005",
      serie1: 10,
      serie2: 15
    }, {
      date: "1.2.2005",
      serie1: 14,
      serie2: 16
    }, {
      date: "1.3.2005",
      serie1: 12,
      serie2: 17
    }, {
      date: "1.4.2005",
      serie1: 19,
      serie2: 21
    }, {
      date: "1.5.2005",
      serie1: 7,
      serie2: 13
    }, {
      date: "1.6.2005",
      serie1: 12,
      serie2: 16
    }, ];


    // Define how dates are presented in the source file
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;

    // Format each series into its own, distinguishable elements
    color = d3.scale.category10();
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));
    lineNames = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
          };
        })
      };
    });

    //Initialize scales. HACK: only selecting scales based on the 1st series
    xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
      return new Date(parseDate(d.date))
    });
    yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
      return +d.serie1
    });
    x = d3.time.scale().domain(xExtent);
    y = d3.scale.linear().domain(yExtent);

    //Initialize axes
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient('bottom');
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient('left');

    //Initialize svg
    svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg');
    chartWrapper = svg.append('g');
    chartWrapper.append('g').classed('x axis', true);
    chartWrapper.append('g').classed('y axis', true);


    // Create lines:

    // Version 1: Hardcoded lines
    line1 = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date)))
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(+d.serie1)
      });

    line2 = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date)))
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(+d.serie2)
      });


    // Version 2: Dynamic lines
    allLines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      let thisName = lineNames[i].name;
      allLines[i] = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(new Date(parseDate(d.date)))
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d[thisName])
        });
    };


    //Paths to all lines
    allPaths = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= allLines.length - 1; i++) {
      allPaths[i] = chartWrapper.append('path').datum(data).classed('line', true);
    };

    //render the chart
    render(data);


    function render(data) {

      margin.top = 100;
      margin.right = 300;
      margin.left = 50;
      margin.bottom = 100;

      width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



      // update x and y scales to new dimensions
      x.range([0, width]);
      y.range([height, 0]);

      // update svg elements to new dimensions
      svg
        .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
      chartWrapper.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      // axes scales 
      xAxis.scale(x);
      yAxis.scale(y);

      // x-axis
      svg.select('.x.axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

      // y-axis
      svg.select('.y.axis')
        .call(yAxis);


      // Draw all lines:

      // Version 1: Harcoded lines
      //allPaths[0].attr('d', line1);
      //allPaths[1].attr('d', line2);
      //allPaths[1].style("stroke", "red")

      // Version 2: Lines from array. COMMENTED OUT SINCE DOESN'T WORK!
      allPaths[0].attr('d', allLines[0]);
      allPaths[1].attr('d', allLines[1]);
      allPaths[1].style("stroke", "red")

    }
  }

)(window, d3);
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```